# run capital-gains command and get erro: AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute 'BooleanOptionalAction'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python library `capital-gains`
I refer https://pypi.org/project/capital-gains/ this python docs.
when I run `capital-gains` command it throws an error:

> AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute
> 'BooleanOptionalAction'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/archana/mantralabs/backend/env/bin/capital-gains", line 8, in
>
> sys.exit(main())   File "/home/archana/mantralabs/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capital_gains/capital_gains.py",
> line 11, in main
> parser = argument_parser.get_parser()   File "/home/archana/mantralabs/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capital_gains/argument_parser.py",
> line 52, in get_parser
> action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute 'BooleanOptionalAction'

Python version - 3.8

Can anyone help me? i'm not able to find out solution on google

Comment: `BooleanOptionalAction` was added in python 3.9. YOu need an older version of that package or a newer version of python.

Comment: yeah, i'll update my python version, Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Actually The **argparse.BooleanOptionalAction** feature is only available in Python 3.9 and above.
you can try with python 3.9 or above version's